# Could not find any tests to run. We looked but did not find a cypress.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, ui-automation, cypress

I have installed Cypress in my project and when I am trying to run the Cypress using `npx cypress run`, it's giving me the following error:

> Could not find any tests to run.
> We looked but did not find a cypress.json file in this folder...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you need to enter `npx cypress open` if you are running for first time. once the project is created then you can use `npx cypress run`

Comment: thank you i completely forgot about the npx cypress open